# How to save ForeignKey in queryset? 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'myfield'

Tags: django

How to save ForeignKey in queryset?

```
class BookFile(models.Model):
   myfile = models.FileField(upload_to="mybooks")

class MyBook(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    file = models.ForeignKey(BookFile)
```

My try in views:

```
bookfile = form.cleaned_data.get('bookfile')
mybook = MyBook.objects.create(number="5555")
mybook.file.myfile = bookfile
mybook.save()
```

Error:

> ```
> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'myfile'
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you get in bookfile ? Is it an object or an id ? If it's an id, you could try:

```
bookfile = form.cleaned_data.get('bookfile')
mybook = MyBook.objects.create(number="5555")

bookFileObject = BookFile.objects.create()
bookFileObject.myfile = bookfile
bookFileObject.save()
mybook.file = bookFileObject
mybook.save()
```

Comment: `bookfile` if file from `input type="file"`

Comment: the pb with your line "mybook.file.myfile = bookfile" is that you try to do 2 things in one row : associated a file + associate a foreignkey